# Creating Zip file with multiple entries in C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, zip

I created the functionality to get documents from blob storage and then add them to a zip file for download.

```
[HttpPost]
        public FileContentResult DownloadDocumentsByDocIDZIP(List<int> documentIDs)
        {

            List<Document> docs = new List<Document>();

            foreach (int doc in documentIDs)
            {

                if (doc != 0)
                {
                    Document document = documentService.GetDocumentByID(doc, false);
                    docs.Add(document);

                }

            }

            MemoryStream outms = new MemoryStream();
            using (ZipArchive zar = new ZipArchive(outms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
            {

                foreach (Document docu in docs)
                {
                    if (docu != null)
                    {

                        byte[] documentdata = documentService.DownloadDocumentData(docu.DocumentID);
                        string name = docu.DocumentNiceName ?? docu.DocumentFileName;
                        byte[] unzipped = documentdata;
                        ZipArchiveEntry entry = zar.CreateEntry(name);
                        Stream str = entry.Open();
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(unzipped);
                        ms.CopyTo(str);
                        

                    }
                }
                outms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
            
            var outdata = outms.ToArray();

            var result = File(outdata, "application/zip", "documents.zip");
            return result;


        }
```

When I hit the function via ajax, It fails at

```
 ZipArchiveEntry entry = zar.CreateEntry(name);
```

I'm given the exception,

System.IO.IOException: 'Entries cannot be created while previously created entries are still open.'

So I added str.close()

```
 using (ZipArchive zar = new ZipArchive(outms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
            {

                foreach (Document docu in docs)
                {
                    if (docu != null)
                    {

                        byte[] documentdata = documentService.DownloadDocumentData(docu.DocumentID);
                        string name = docu.DocumentNiceName ?? docu.DocumentFileName;
                        byte[] unzipped = documentdata;
                        ZipArchiveEntry entry = zar.CreateEntry(name);
                        Stream str = entry.Open();
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(unzipped);
                        ms.CopyTo(str);
                        str.Close();

                    }
                }
                outms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
            
            var outdata = outms.ToArray();

            var result = File(outdata, "application/zip", "documents.zip");
            return result;
```

Now it creates the file but when you try to unzip it after download.

It gives me an error in WinZip. Error: unable to seek to beginning of Central Directory.

Can someone please assist I have no idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have to dispose the Stream before add new stream to zip but the real problem is that you call Seek on stream, try the following code:

```
using (ZipArchive zar = new ZipArchive(outms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
{

   foreach (Document docu in docs)
   {
      if (docu != null)
      {

         byte[] documentdata = documentService.DownloadDocumentData(docu.DocumentID);
                        string name = docu.DocumentNiceName ?? docu.DocumentFileName;
         byte[] unzipped = documentdata;
         ZipArchiveEntry entry = zar.CreateEntry(name);
         using (Stream str = entry.Open())
         {
            str.Write(unzipped);
         }
      }
   }
   //outms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  //This causes "Error: unable to seek to beginning of Central Directory."
}
            
var outdata = outms.ToArray();

var result = File(outdata, "application/zip", "documents.zip");
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried implementing the changes you suggested but to no avail. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Same error during unzip?

Comment: Jip the same error.

Comment: Strange beahviour.. Have you tried to open the resulting zip with another software like 7zip or Windows default zip viewer? With the changes I've made I can download and view/extract the zip with no errors.